# Volume loss upon exporting wav from Ableton Live

Tags: ableton-live, volume, wav

Upon exporting track to a wav , it creates a very quiet file **as opposed to the volume while playing in Ableton Live .**
I export my master channel of course, which db, frequencies and mastering are fine, sound wise. 
There's a limiter for 0 db on my master track; though I tried taking it off, using other limiters, normalizing upon export, changing values - and anything I could possibly think of. 
The wav file loses a lot of the track's volume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wav file is fine! The problem was on the other end - Winamp;
For some reason "Microsoft sound mapper" was highlighted.
Selected my sound card instead of "Microsoft sound mapper" in WaveOut settings - volume is up again.

[image: winamp wav output]

(Never had volume issues with MP3 or FLAC files though)

Comment: Winamp handles WAV files just fine.  Although, I suppose it is possible there is something strange about your WAV file.  Is it in 24-bit?  Alternatively, you have a plugin or configuration (check your eq) in Winamp causing this issue.

Comment: You're using a 32-bit WAV file, I'm not surprised in this case.

Comment: Please add further info regard 32-bit WAV